# Can you describe how ....?

Tags: tense

What would you choose? And why?

```
1. Can you descrive how ....?

a. does RAM work?

b. RAM works?

c. is RAM working? 

d. has RAM benn working?
```

I am deciding between A and B. Do I need use "does" or not?

```
2. Pete ..... at least eight beeers since we came here.

a. drank

b. has drunk

c. drunk

d. has been drinking.
```

Comment: Embedded question doesn't need a do-support and subject-auxiliary inversion. So *RAM works* is correct. I think the latter should be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking a general question about RAM

> Can you describe how **RAM works**?

is appropriate.

In your second example, since he has already consumed the beers, the past tense is used

> Pete **drank** at least eight beers since we came here.

could be used to describe his consumption.  In this situation **drunk** might not be used since it might be conduces that you are saying "he is *already* **drunk**".  Usually your sentence would be expressed as

> Pete **has already had** at least eight beers since we came here.